# I have problems with (Mason) lsp server rust-analyzer

Tags: neovim, rust-analyzer

I am new to Neovim. I have install neovim v0.9 and copied lua configuration from [kickstart.nvim](https://github.com/nvim-lua/kickstart.nvim). I have followed all the instructions as per TJ's youtube video too. Everything is working perfectly fine. Lsp is working for ts and lua. But Lsp recognizes rust file (:LspInfo shows that it has recognized rust file) yet autocomplete stuff isn't happening for rust.

I have tried all the configurations mentioned in mason repo. I do not know why it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

3 ways you can solve this issue.

1. Uninstalling `rust-analyzer` from rustup ( rustup installs an unusable version of this package. see [this reply](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-analyzer/issues/14759#issuecomment-1544574240) )

   ```
    mv ~/.cargo/bin/rust-analyzer ~/.backup/rust-analyzer`
   ```

**or**

2. On macOS Installing `rust-analyzer` with **homebrew**

   ```
    brew install rust-analyzer
   ```

**or**

3. In your **~/.config/nvim/lua/core/init.lua** file replace **line:61** with `vim.env.PATH = vim.fn.stdpath "data" .. "/mason/bin" .. (is_windows and "; " or ":") .. vim.env.PATH`. This will add **~/.local/share/nvim/mason/bin/** at the beginning of your PATH. (from [issue #1289](https://github.com/williamboman/mason.nvim/issues/1289#issuecomment-1549875448) )

   ```lua
   --   ~/.config/nvim/lua/core/init.lua
        59 -- add binaries installed by mason.nvim to path
   ...
   ---> 61 vim.env.PATH = vim.env.PATH .. (is_windows and "; " or ":") .. vim.fn.stdpath "data" .. "/mason/bin"
   +++> 61 vim.env.PATH = vim.fn.stdpath "data" .. "/mason/bin" .. (is_windows and "; " or ":") .. vim.env.PATH
   ```

Then add `rust_analyzer` to **lspconfig.lua**.

( If using **NvChad** edit **~/.config/nvim/lua/custom/configs/lspconfig.lua** to add 
`local servers=(... "rust_analyzer")` )

In work directory make sure project has a Cargo.toml file

```
cargo init
nvim main.rs
```

see [this issue](https://github.com/williamboman/mason.nvim/issues/1289#issuecomment-1544448868) to know the problem, also see [this reply](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-analyzer/issues/14759#issuecomment-1539720043)

Comment: This fixed my issue, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

If the LSP is being recognised, but not loaded, that usually indicates that the binary could not be executed for some reason. Possible reasons include:

1. The binary is not on the PATH (exact instruction will depend on the operating system)
2. The binary was not executable (wonky permissions, or an invalid binary)
3. The binary aborted for some reason (check :LspLog for details)

Answer (score 0):

Add mason/bin at the start of path in shell config file

```
# ~/.bashrc
export PATH="$HOME/.local/share/nvim/mason/bin/:$PATH"
```